# Regex allow words that have an apostrophe but does not end in a specific letter like "s"

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to make a regex that contains an apostrophe but doesn't end with a specific letter, like 's' for example.

I haven't had much luck as of yet, I've tried:

```
([a-z])|(?!s\b)
```

but that doesn't seem to produce the correct output, not really sure how you would do it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where's the apostrophe?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. It would help if you provided a [mre] including some example input (text) and your expected output (matches). The regex you wrote isn't even close, so it would help to understand exactly what you're going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```regex
[a-z']+(?<!s)\b
```

Explanation:

- `[a-z']` - Any character in the range a-z or an apostrophe

  - `+` - One or more of the preceding
- `(?<!s)` - Previous character is not `s`
- `\b` - Word boundary

Example input:

```
don't match words ending in s
```

Matches:

```
don't
match
ending
in
```

[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XItUnZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can assert a whitespace boundaries at the left and right, and assert that there is no `s` directly to the left at the end.

```
(?<!\S)[a-z']+(?!\S)(?<!s)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the left
- `[a-z']+` Match 1+ times either a char a-z or `'`
- `(?!\S)(?<!s)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right, and assert not `s` to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m84777/1)

**Note** that this could also match a standalone `'`